# Sorting on varchar field as integer in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has three fields: "Id, Name, Sequence".
In the "Sequence" column there are the following entries: 1, 2, 3, 4, 2a, 5, 2b, 2c, 3, 4a (Row wise).

Now I want to a mysql query which can sort these values like:

1, 2, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3, 4, 4a, 5.

I have tried following query

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY CAST(sequence AS UNSIGNED) ASC`.
But it's not working.

Comment: you don't need anything but `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY sequence asc`

Comment: @senape that will put `10` before `2` since the field is `varchar` not numeric.

Comment: @lurker you're right, I didn't think about it. actually, I tested with cast(sequence as unsigned) and it worked as expected.

Comment: @senape `cast(sequence as unsigned)` by itself doesn't work, either. It doesn't subsort `2`, `2a`, `2b` for example. If your list has `2b`, `2`, `2a`, then it leaves that order.

Comment: @lurker, i just tested it, and it worked

Comment: @senape, no it doesn't. See [this example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91ea4a/2). `3b` comes before `3`, but it shouldn't.

Comment: ok, i see. sorry.

Comment: @lurker, i will clean up this chat, since it's helpless for future references. thanks for teaching me something i didn't know, anyway :)

Comment: @senape no worries. At very first, I thought the `cast(sequence as unsigned)` was sufficient too until I considered more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to order by the integer first, then order by the substring after the number by just ordering by the whole string as the sub-sort:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY CAST(sequence AS UNSIGNED), sequence;
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91ea4a/1) with an example. I left off the `ASC` since that's the default.

Comment: @VirendraPratapSingh that's great! If you could be so kind as to accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to it, I would appreciate it.